# Multicast socket library in C

Tags: c, sockets

Is there a socket library that sets up multi cast sockets properly and operates the signal and read/write operations in C?

I have tried many online resources but I am trying to operate several multicast from a single process which is a bit daunting.

Comment: Off-topic. You should first make clear at which level you want to handle multicasts.

Comment: Checkout ZEROMQ, it has plenty network architectures. But your question is too open, try to narrow it down.